# Encountering .NET concurrency errors after copying DB tables with DataGrip

Tags: .net, docker, entity-framework, amazon-rds, datagrip

I was recently migrating some MySQL tables from one Amazon Aurora DB to another using the DataGrip -> "Copy To..." command (we needed to update a few tables and I thought I could quickly do so with the existing tools). This service allows you to migrate tables from one DataSource to another without requiring a data dump or the exporting of an RDS snapshot. After completing this migration, I was encountering the following error in the AWS environment:

The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions..

My code is configured using .NET's Entity Framework to instantiate and interface with the Database in our AWS environment. This .NET application is running inside of a .NET container and contains the same code when run in AWS and when run locally. When testing the application from my local machine, by port forwarding requests through a bastion host to the RDS cluster, I was able to connect and communicate with the DB without any issue. However, when the application was deployed into an AWS ECS Fargate task, the EF client would return the error above when the application attempts to write to some of the specific tables in the DB.

Why is it that this is working from my local environment but the same EF client cannot write to the DB?

Any additional insight as to how/why the code would perform differently in AWS as opposed to when it was running on my local machine.

Comment: Any chance you can repeat this task using the copy to table option and close the IDE afterward? See if the issue reoccurs by closing DataGrip client after copying is finished.

Also, is there anything specific about the tables you have copied? Let us know your results

Comment: I ran it again and this time and another set of tables returned the same error. I had originally ran the copy several weeks ago and forgot I had done it. We then implemented a new ECS task and it began spitting out the "he database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions" error.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - for anyone encountering this issue in the future.

The way I resolved this issue was by dropping the tables which had been copied using DataGrip. I then exported those same tables using mysqldump and I imported them into the second RDS cluster. I think this had to do with the DataGrip tool not locking the tables when it was completing the copies. Whenever the client attempted to write to the DB a concurrency lock was preventing the .Save() action.

I was unable to find anything about this happening in my research and I was only able to recognize this issue after some dumb luck. Be careful with how you export data from a live environment.

Are there any ideas as to why the container running on my Windows 11 machine was able to write to the DB but the ECS Fargate task wasn't able to?